# PHP input sanitizer function?

Tags: php, security, sanitization

What's a method to sanitize PHP POST data for passing to a mail function? (I prefer a method that's not part of the `mysql_function()` family of functions.)

I take the data, sanitize it, print it back to the user and send it in an email to a preset address.

**EDIT:**
I'm just sending the email to our email address so we can send out a mailing to the address in the email.

Comment: That depends on what the mail function is doing with the data.

Comment: @IshKumar, Not a dupe, I don't want to use a library.

Comment: @cdhowie - I want to send the email to an address! That's all.

Comment: Don't sanitize input, sanitize output.

Comment: @Moshe: Why should that require any sanitizing at all?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, no. to prevent code injection, we sanitize input.

Comment: @Moshe The input code doesn't know what kind of sanitization the sink function needs. There are so many ways to escape/sanitize data(html, sql, file-path,...) and the input layer of the code doesn't know which one to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're printing it back to the user, you need to escape any HTML content.

`strip_tags()`
and
`html_special_chars()` are quite useful in filtering the message content, especially if you're using html messages.

See also:
[How to sanitze user input in PHP before mailing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055460/how-to-sanitze-user-input-in-php-before-mailing)
which mentions doing a find & replace on newlines that could allow injecting content into the mail headers.
As you're using a pre-set mail address the risk is reduced, but the subject field is still vulnerable.

Comment: There's no good reason to escape HTML in an email.. especially if it's a plaintext email.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, But what about sanitizing for the handling of the data before I send the email?

Comment: Certainly, but we don't know what he's doing with the email. Covering all the bases, even if you only expect text emails at the start, is a good tactic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the filter functions 
e.g http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0):

Sanitizing for an e-mail would be equivalent to sanitizing for HTML output. I see some suggestions on SO for [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: Why would you escape HTML in a plaintext email? I think he wants to protect against header injection.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Who said anything about plain text? Most of the emails are HTML nowadays so they should be checked for HTML injection. I don't think he referred to header injection. Why would he print the headers back to the user?

Comment: Most emails are HTML? Not really.. luckily. HTML emails are a pest.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I don't know what mails you receive or send but what I use and work with is HTML.