# Is "strip_tags" sufficient for contact form security?

Tags: php, security, phpmailer, contact-form

I've got a contact form on my website, which submits the post value of the user's name, email address, subject, and message, to a function that sends the email using phpmailer. Is using strip_tags sufficient to make this form secure? I haven't implemented this yet.

```
function sendEmail($mail, $to, $subject, $senderName, $from, $message) {
    if((!empty($to)) && (!empty($subject)) && (!empty($senderName)) && (!empty($from)) && (!empty($message))) {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = '[REDACTED]';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = '[REDACTED]';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '[REDACTED]';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom($from, $senderName); //
        $mail->addAddress('[REDACTED]', '[REDACTED]');     // Add a recipient. Hardcoded email address
        $mail->addReplyTo($from, $senderName);

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = "<h1>You've received a message through the contact form at chriscomposes.com</h1><br><br>" . $message;
        $mail->AltBody = "You've received a message through the contact form at chriscomposes.com." . $message;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            return "<p style='margin-left: 5px; color: red;'>Message failed to send.</p>";
        } else {
            return "<p style='margin-left: 5px; color: green;'>Message has been sent.</p>";
        }   
    } else {
        return "<p style='margin-left: 5px; color: red;'>One or more fields are empty. Please enter a subject, name, email address, and message.</p>";
    }
}
```

^ That is the function it runs. With the hardcoded email address, I don't think it would be vulnerable to someone using the form to send emails with. One other concern is that the user receiving the address would be vulnerable to javascript inserted into the email.

This is the form: [image]

Then it posts with this: `sendEmail($mail, $contactEmail, $_POST['subject'], $_POST['sender_name'], $_POST['sender_email'], $_POST['body']);` with $contactEmail being an address pulled from my database. Then that function sends the email address using phpmailer.

Comment: Is there any user input going into this?

Comment: You should post any code that is filtering the message, you mention **strip_tags** but don't show it.

Comment: I don't know of any email client that runs javascript, so XSS does not apply unless you are also redisplaying the submitted content back on a 'thanks' page. Don't use the submitter's email address as the `from` address as it will make you fail SPF checks; put it in `reply-to` instead. Why are you passing in the `$mail` instance? Looks like it might be better to have it as a local static, or you need to be careful that you clear recipients between invocations.

Comment: The $mail variable is outside the functions scope, and it throws a server error if you don't pass the mail object. Thanks for the heads up about SPF checks. That's really useful. Would it work to set from as webmaster@mydomain.com, and name of from as mydomain.com. Or simply set the email address as webmaster@mydomain.com and the name can be the name of the person sending the message?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to check the message to ensure no headers have been injected with To:, CC: and BCC: which would allow spammers to send email off your form.

This post has additional information: [How to sanitze user input in PHP before mailing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055460/how-to-sanitze-user-input-in-php-before-mailing)

Comment: The function I'm running shouldn't allow this, it takes very specific variables, then runs another function to send the email. And the to address is hardcoded in the function. 

I guess my biggest concern is scripting attacks. Although even so, I tried a simple test of putting "<script>alert(1)</script>" into the name field and submitting and nothing happened (haven't used strip_tags yet), so there may be no worries at all

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a data filtering function called `filter_var` that you can use for this.

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php

Concidering the email address, subject and body are all user input data,

```
$sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$sanitizedSubject = filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$sanitizedBody = filter_val($body, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` will remove tags and encode special chars.
`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` will remove line breaks, since you won't be needing those in your subject field.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can use PHP Function to sanitize each INPUT:

```
<?php

 $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

?>
```

Or you can create an array for args and pass all validations:

```
<?php

$args = [
    'name'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'email'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
    'address' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'message' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
];

$myInputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

?>
```

This to prevent XSS attacks.

Here all type filters: [Input Filters PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

And, as extra tip, after sanitize each "INPUT" you can simplify the "EMPTY" check, using only "ISSET" (is more fast):

```
<?php
    if(isset($to{1}, $subject{1}, $senderName{1}, $from{1}, $message{1}))
    {
      //code...
    }
?>
```

This it means that all variables must to have at least a char, otherwise, the code will never be executed.

Comment: Awesome. So this would protect the site and the user receiving the emails?

Comment: Basically, this filters as their name says, make a clean up of the inputs POST or GET. This filter can remove extra tags and converts the variables to text-plain.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to receive secured input data is to build a security model for data.

One should define what are the data which can be inputted in form and what the system need to receive.

Based on that knowledge one should validate and filter everything except what is really needed.

So if you know what are you doing you should now if that function, method or better approach is enough to secure data.

One should never rely on simple function but should use a modeling approach.

P.S. Please read more about input data validation [Data Validation](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Input-Validation.html).